# VBA intersect range should only work in sheets having the defined target range but bypass that request

Tags: vba

In order to reinitialize a child drop down (drop down 2 depending of the choice made in drop down 1), I have the below code in "ThisWorkbook".

It is supposed to clear the content of the child drop down if a cell from a specific range (where is drop down 1) change.
It works fine on the sheet where this range name exist (range name is "RSTcabFINISHING").

## ISSUE

on any other sheet (= sheet where this range name does not exist), this code is clearing the content of any 3 cells right to a cell I change the content.

Solution would be to put the code only on the sheet that need it I suppose. But (tell me If I'm wrong) it looks making more sense to put the code in "ThisWorkbook" since the sheet having the range described above are subject to be multiplied (=copy)...

not sure all of this make sense... I guess the question is "what should should I do to avoid this clearing content happening anywhere else than where I want?".

Thx!

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'Initialize cabinet finishing board
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("RSTcabFINISHING")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
End If

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem(s) stem mostly from using `On Error Resume Next`.

1. Your if statement will throw an error if the range doesn't exist. This means it won't be evaluated and instead, you drop through to the next line because of resume next.
2. Now it'll disable events. As such, your event will only trigger once, as you never seem to re-enable it.
3. Now it'll clear all the contents, without ever having tested your intersect was valid.

So, we need to do two things:

1. Fix up the evaluation
2. Ditch the Application.EnableEvents = false, or at least fix it. Most events only raise by the user making changes rather than the VBA script, so you likely can ignore this entirely.

The best way to fix this up would be to call a safer function that verifies the range exists, and returns true or false depending on that result.

Something like this may be more useful to you:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Initialize cabinet finishing board
    If RangeExists("RSTcabFINISHING") Then          'See below for what this does. We only progress if we get true.
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("RSTcabFINISHING")) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function RangeExists(RangeName As String)
    On Error GoTo NotValid:             'If we fail, jump to "NotValid"
    If Range(RangeName).Rows >= 0 Then  'Test if the range exists - if it doesn't we'll get an error, if it does it
                                        'will have 0 or more rows
        RangeExists = True              'We didn't error and we do have 0 or more rows, so the function is true
    End If
    Exit Function                       'Break out of the function before we hit our error handler
NotValid:                               'We only get this far if an error was thrown (Range doesn't exist)
    RangeExists = False                 'Flag the function as false before returning
End Function
```

Comment: Thx @Jonno 

Solution fully makes sense, however I can't make it work.
Not sure how that 1 line works in the function: If Range(RangeName).Rows >= 0 Then... Shouldn't I declare what "rangeName" actually is?

Comment: @AdriendeHarlez It is declared in `Function RangeExists(RangeName As String)`, it's passed into it by calling `RangeExists("RSTcabFINISHING")`.